# Wordpress + BigBlueButton + Php api

Tags: php, wordpress, bigbluebutton

I am working with BigBlueButton's php api and am trying to figure out how to get a wordpress username INSTEAD of the user having to enter their name if they are logged in.  If any of you fine folks can help, it would be much appreciated! Some of the code:

```
$step = 3;
    }
    break;
case 'enter':
    /*
     * The user is now attempting to join the meeting
     */

    if (trim($_REQUEST['username'])&& trim($_REQUEST['meetingID'])){
        $bbb_joinURL = BigBlueButton::joinURL($_REQUEST['meetingID'], $_REQUEST['username'],"ap", $salt, $url);
        //$joinURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?action=join&username='.urlencode($_REQUEST['$current_user']).'&meetingToken='.urlencode($_REQUEST['meetingToken']);

        if (BigBlueButton::isMeetingRunning( $_REQUEST['meetingID'], $url, $salt ))
        {
        ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          window.location.href="<?php echo $bbb_joinURL;?>";
        </script>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             * The meeting has not yet started, so check until we get back the status that the meeting is running
             */
            $step = 4;

            $checkMeetingStatus = BigBlueButton::getMeetingInfoURL( $_REQUEST['meetingID'], 'mp', $url, $salt );
        }
    }
    else if (!$_REQUEST['username']){
        $msg = "You must enter your name.";
        $step = 3;
    }
    break;
case 'isMeetingRunning':
    /*
     * This function proxy the request "isMeetingRunning" through PHP Script to BBB Server so we don't have any AJAX security issue
     */
    ob_clean();
    $checkMeetingStatus = BigBlueButton::isMeetingRunningURL( $_REQUEST['meetingID'], $url, $salt );
    echo file_get_contents($checkMeetingStatus);
    die;
    break;
case 'join':
    /*
     * We have an invite request to join an existing meeting and the meeting is running
     * We don't need to pass a meeting description as it's already been set by the first time the meeting was created.
     */
    $bbb_joinURL = BigBlueButton::joinURL($_REQUEST['meetingID'], $_REQUEST['username'],"ap", $salt, $url);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt not quite understand your question. But you can access the username of wordpress as

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if($user_id){
    $user_information = get_userdata($user_id);
    $username = $user_information->user_login;
}
else{
//write you previous code where you ask user to post their name if not logged in 
}
```

Under the table $wpdb->users, the column user_login stores the username that users enter on signing up in WordPress site through WordPress login panel

Comment: Thank you, that does help some. In my code above, I would like to log the user in under their wordpress username if they are logged in, and if not, have them enter their name to join the conference. Hope that is a little more clear.